# double click at single link

Tags: php, jquery, double-click

As we can see that in some banking website pages and some so secure website where when we **double click at single link , refreshing the page (F5)/window-reload-btn , click link/button during loading** - In this all situation when happens page redirect to error page or logout.
PHP as programming language *Can we do this or make this function im PHP ?* else is able to make in jQuery? How.

Comment: i didnt get what you looking for , on double click to refesh the page ?

Comment: Ops, I tried my best to elaborate, ghe basic problem at stackoverflow is peoples send *we couldn't understand wjat you mean* and then mark as votedown I don't know what they gotting in votedown some peoples. everyone have right to own, atleast he ask once before someone votedown. well, I want *when I double click at btn/link repetitive , window f5, then page redirect to error.html*

Answer (score 0):

something like this will do the trick

```js
      $('button, a').dblclick(function(){
        location.reload();
        var click = true;

        if (click) {
          click = false;
          window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Double Click Me</button>
<a href="#">Double Click Me</a>
```

**UPDATE**

Your example is writen on asp.net that can handle this state im not sure if jquery can handle that kind of event but you can try something like that

This should go on the page where you want to detect F5 , i didnt test it but should work , or this can be done with sessionStorage

```
var loaded = false;
 $(window).on('load', function(){
  loaded = true;
 });

if(!loaded){
  $(document.body).on("keydown", this, function(event) { 
      if(event.keyCode == 116){ 
      alert('page is still loading . Please wait'); 
       } 
 });
}
```

You can try with sessionStorage i didnt test if but should work

```
sessionStorage.setItem('loaded ', false)
$(window).on('load', function(){
 lsessionStorage.setItem('loaded ', true)
});

if(lsessionStorage.loaded != true){
 $(document.body).on("keydown", this, function(event) { 
     if(event.keyCode == 116){ 
     alert('page is still loading . Please wait'); 
       } 
 });
}
```

Comment: Great, Now supposed page is still loading amd you pressed again reload/f5 == double reload request - redirect.errorpage.

Comment: @SatyamKumar i did not get what the problem now, you mean if page is still loading and you press f5 to rederict to error page ?

Comment: yes, please see this example (visit >> `https://www.bobibanking.com/` >> click Retail User btn >> Login Page (reload the page/double click at single link= redirect to error page)

Comment: have you seen that?

Comment: what you do mean session storage, how we utilize this in session ? php

Comment: same as var loaded set session before page load and update same session after page loaded then on refresh check if session loaded is true or false and execute the function if is false

Comment: could you explain in via full code. really I not understand belive me.

Comment: @lvan I really not understand pls explain in code, it would be your really veey great help finally

Comment: is same like updated answer just replace var loadded with sessionStorage.setItem('name', value) and replace if(!loaded) with if(sessionStorage.name != true)